# Payara server not boot after a power failure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

Payara server not boot after a power failure.
how I can fix and save payaradomain, I have many configurations there.
domain1 works well.
[image]

Comment: Well its an XML parse error, so it would be logical to assume one of the XML files of payaradomain got damaged somehow. Nothing to do but check the configuration files manually. You did try emptying the 'generated' folder first, just in case?

Comment: emptying the 'generated' folder not work.anyway thanks.

Comment: payaradomain\config\domain.xml is damaged

Comment: Unfortunate but as expected, so not much that can be done with this question here.

Comment: Check for a `domain.xml.bak` file. You may be able to overwrite the corrupted domain.xml with the autogenerated backup. This link describes it more for an older version of GlassFish in the "backup" section: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/abhar/index.html

Comment: thanks @Mike. Its working

Comment: Good news! I added the comment as an answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a `domain.xml.bak` file in the same directory as the `domain.xml`. You may be able to overwrite the corrupted domain.xml with the autogenerated backup.

This link describes it more for an older version of GlassFish in the "backup" section:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/abhar/index.html